# Confusion on C++ Python extensions. Things like getting C++ values for python values

Tags: c++, python, api, module

I'm wanted to convert some of my python code to C++ for speed but it's not as easy as simply making a C++ function and making a few function calls. I have no idea how to get a C++ integer from a python integer object. I have an integer which is an attribute of an object that I want to use. I also have integers which are inside a list in the object which I need to use.

I wanted to test making a C++ extension with this function:

```
def setup_framebuffer(surface,flip=False):
   #Create texture if not done already
   if surface.texture is None:
      create_texture(surface)
   #Render child to parent
   if surface.frame_buffer is None:
      surface.frame_buffer = glGenFramebuffersEXT(1)
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, c_uint(int(surface.frame_buffer)))
   glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture, 0)
   glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT)
   glViewport(0,0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1])
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glLoadIdentity() #Load the projection matrix
   if flip:
      gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1],0)
   else:
      gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],0,surface._scale[1])
```

That function calls create_texture, so I will have to pass that function to the C++ function which I will do with the third argument. This is what I have so far, while trying to follow information on the python documentation:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
   ...
   {"setup_framebuffer",  setup_framebuffer, METH_VARARGS,"Loads a texture from a Surface object to the OpenGL framebuffer."},
   ...
   {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};
static PyObject * setup_framebuffer(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
   bool flip;
   PyObject *create_texture, *arg_list,*pyflip,*frame_buffer_id;
   if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOO", &surface,&pyflip,&create_texture)){
      return NULL;
   }
   if (PyObject_IsTrue(pyflip) == 1){
      flip = true;
   }else{
      flip = false;
   }
   Py_XINCREF(create_texture);
   //Create texture if not done already
   if(texture == NULL){
      arglist = Py_BuildValue("(O)", surface)
      result = PyEval_CallObject(create_texture, arglist);
      Py_DECREF(arglist);
      if (result == NULL){
         return NULL;
      }
      Py_DECREF(result);
   }
   Py_XDECREF(create_texture);
   //Render child to parent
   frame_buffer_id = PyObject_GetAttr(surface, Py_BuildValue("s","frame_buffer"))
   if(surface.frame_buffer == NULL){
      glGenFramebuffersEXT(1,frame_buffer_id);
   }
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, surface.frame_buffer));
   glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, surface.texture, 0);
   glPushAttrib(GL_VIEWPORT_BIT);
   glViewport(0,0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1]);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity(); //Load the projection matrix
   if (flip){
      gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],surface._scale[1],0);
   }else{
      gluOrtho2D(0,surface._scale[0],0,surface._scale[1]);
   }
   Py_INCREF(Py_None);
   return Py_None;
}
PyMODINIT_FUNC initcscalelib(void){
   PyObject *module;
   module = Py_InitModule("cscalelib", Methods);
   if (m == NULL){
      return;
   }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   /* Pass argv[0] to the Python interpreter */
   Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
   /* Initialize the Python interpreter.  Required. */
   Py_Initialize();
   /* Add a static module */
   initscalelib();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get a C `int` from a Python integer is with `PyInt_AsLong()` and a downcast (although you may want to use a C long instead.) To go the other way, you call `PyInt_FromLong()`. It's not obvious to me where in the code you want to do this, although I do have a couple of other comments about your code:

- Conceptually, `PyObject_IsTrue()` returns a boolean. Don't compare it to 1, just use it as a boolean value. However, you *should* check if it returned an error, which would be -1. (The usual check is `< 0`.) If you don't check for error returns you end up swallowing the exception, but leaving the exception object hanging around. This is bad.
- The `Py_XINCREF()` of `create_texture` is not necessary. You have a borrowed reference to the `args` tuple, which in turn owns a reference to the `create_texture` object. There is no way for `create_texture` to go away before your function returns. You only need to incref it if you are going to keep it around longer than this functioncall. If you did have to incref it, you wouldn't need to use `Py_XINCREF()` because it won't ever be NULL. And if you did have to incref it, you would need to remember to decref it in your error return case, as well.
- Instead of creating an argument tuple just to call `PyEval_CallObject()`, just call `PyObject_CallFunctionObjectArgs(create_texture, arglist, NULL)` or `PyObject_CallFunction(create_texture, "O", arglist)`.
- `Py_BuildValue("s", "frame_buffer")` is not really the right way to get a Python string for `"frame_buffer"`. A better way is `PyString_FromString()`. However, both of those return new references, and `PyObject_GetAttr()` doesn't eat the reference to the attribute name, so you end up leaking that reference. You should use none of these, and instead use `PyObject_GetAttrString()`, which takes the attribute name as a `const char*`.
- Remember to check the return value of *all* functions that can return an error value (which is almost all Python API functions.) Besides `PyTrue_IsTrue()` you're also forgetting this for `Py_BuildValue()` and `PyObject_GetAttr()`.

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful. I've managed to get the code to compile fine but there is an import error:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/cscalelib.so, 2): Symbol not found: _glBindFramebufferEXT
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/cscalelib.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup


Why doesn't glBindFramebufferEXT work? I haven't got the foggiest idea.

But thank you very much.

Comment: Oh and I compiled on Mac OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.3

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to link to the library that provides that symbol (-lGL, perhaps.)

Comment: Thank you. And I should need -lGLU as wel. I don't know how to do this with distutils. I'll take a look and reply as soon as I find out if I manage to.

Comment: No, I can't get it working. I've tried the libraries argument for the Extension function or constructor and that doesn't work for everything I put into it.

Comment: Nor does -framework OpenGL :(

"linker input file unused because linking not done"

Now I remember why I gave up on C++ beforehand.

Comment: It's more of a question about linking to OpenGL on MacOS now, but it still sounds like you're not linking correctly. I don't know about frameworks on MacOS, though, so I can't really be of help, but I would recommend posting a new question with an accurate description and (at least) your setup.py file and the compiler commands it emits.

Comment: I'm going to try compiling straight from a gcc command first and then I'll start a new question if it fails.

Thank you once again. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 2):

May I make a sincere suggestion here? Instead of throwing a hundred lines of code at yourself when trying something new like this, first try the simplest test case possible. Try getting a C++ extension to work that does nothing but pass back the value 123. (Picking 0 or 1 might accidentally work, so I chose an easy to recognize value that is not likely to be an accident.) Then get the extension to double a number you pass in, then add two numbers, etc.

Sneak up on the problem! :-)

Comment: My idea was to learn as much as possible so I can get to converting the code I need without having to learn in small stages.

Maybe you are right.

Thank you for the answer.